# Pine Script: IF vs IFF

Tags: pine-script

Back to basics for me..  Cant seem to figure out the real difference between an "if" and "iff" statement and I'm not finding much information that explains in detail.  "Iff" and "?:" have the same functionality I gather.

Here is some sample code that behaves differently depending on which if/iff function I use.

'''

```
longStop = input(title="Stop", type=input.bool, defval=false)

//following works fine when passed to plot funtion
longStpTransp = iff(longStop, 0, 100)

//following does not work when passed to plot function
longStpTransp = if (longStop == true)
    0
else
    100

//also does not work when passed to plot function
longStpTransp = 100
if (longStop == true)
    longStpTransp := 0
else
    longStpTransp := 100
                                       

plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? longStopPrice : na, color=color.red, 
style=plot.style_linebr, transp=longStpTransp, linewidth=4, title="Long  Stop")
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. All these are functionally equivalent.

> `if then else`
> `iff`
> `?:`

`iff` does exactly the same thing as ternary conditional operator `?:` but in a functional style.
Also `iff` is slightly less efficient than operator `?:`

Both your examples plot correctly.

Example 1

```
//@version=4
study("IF", "IF", false)

longStop = input(title="Stop", type=input.bool, defval=false)

//following does not work when passed to plot function
longStpTransp = if (longStop == true)
    0
else
    100

plot(longStpTransp)
```

Example 2

```
//@version=4
study("IF", "IF", false)

longStop = input(title="Stop", type=input.bool, defval=false)

//also does not work when passed to plot function
longStpTransp = 100
if (longStop == true)
    longStpTransp := 0
else
    longStpTransp := 100

plot(longStpTransp)
```

**Edit 1** in response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662632/pine-script-if-vs-iff/66663054?noredirect=1#comment117848560_66663054)
That's an interesting observation.
The `transp=` parameter in the `plot()` function needs to be a fixed integer.
So it cannot be a mutable variable.
The value returned by `iff()` is not seen as a mutable variable, but when using `if`, it seems to be seen as a mutable variable and is rejected.
I didn't know this myself.
I was under the assumption that `iff()` and `if-then-else` were identical.
Apparently that is not the case.

> **transp (input integer)** Transparency of the plot. Possible values are from 0 (not transparent) to 100 (invisible). Optional argument.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but in my example I'm not ploting "longStpTransp."  I'm ploting "longStopPrice" with "longStpTransp" as a variable for transparency.  If I use the if/then/else function to pass a value to "longStpTransp" I get a "cannot call plot with argument" error.  But if I use the IFF function to do the same thing it works fine.  I'd just like to know why for my own understanding.

Comment: Added Edit 1 section to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for following up on this.  This has been driving my crazy and thought for sure I was doing something wrong because everything I've read online says that they are identical in function.  Clearly that's not the case.. thank you for confirming my suspicion.