# How to fix "iff" error for pine-script version 5 for customizing Cyclic Smoothed RSI

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to upgrade a customized version of "Cyclic Smoothed RSI" an open community script available on TradingView. But encountering the following error -

> line 43: Could not find function or function reference 'iff'.

The code is as follows -

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="csRSI-EMA", shorttitle="csRSI-EMA")
src = close
domcycle = input.int(20, minval=10, title="Dominant Cycle Length")
crsi = 0.0
cyclelen = domcycle / 2
vibration = 10
leveling = 10.0
cyclicmemory = domcycle * 2
//set min/max ranges?

h1 = hline(30, color=color.silver, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)
h2 = hline(70, color=color.silver, linestyle=hline.style_dashed)

torque = 2.0 / (vibration + 1)
phasingLag = (vibration - 1) / 2.0

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(src), 0), cyclelen)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(src), 0), cyclelen)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - 100 / (1 + up / down)
crsi := torque * (2 * rsi - rsi[phasingLag]) + (1 - torque) * nz(crsi[1])

lmax = -999999.0
lmin = 999999.0
for i = 0 to cyclicmemory - 1 by 1
    if nz(crsi[i], -999999.0) > lmax
        lmax := nz(crsi[i])
        lmax
    else
        if nz(crsi[i], 999999.0) < lmin
            lmin := nz(crsi[i])
            lmin

mstep = (lmax - lmin) / 100
aperc = leveling / 100

db = 0.0
for steps = 0 to 100 by 1
    testvalue = lmin + mstep * steps
    above = 0
    below = 0
    for m = 0 to cyclicmemory - 1 by 1
        below := below + iff(crsi[m] < testvalue, 1, 0)
        below

    ratio = below / cyclicmemory
    if ratio >= aperc
        db := testvalue
        break
    else
        continue

ub = 0.0
for steps = 0 to 100 by 1
    testvalue = lmax - mstep * steps
    above = 0
    for m = 0 to cyclicmemory - 1 by 1
        above := above + iff(crsi[m] >= testvalue, 1, 0)
        above

    ratio = above / cyclicmemory
    if ratio >= aperc
        ub := testvalue
        break
    else
        continue

//EMA with Signal
//Inputs
len = input(9, minval=1, title="Length")
srcema = crsi
smoothingLength = input(title = "Length", defval = 5, minval = 1, maxval = 100, group="Smoothing")
offset = input(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
//Calculation
ma = ta.ema(srcema, len)
sigline = ta.sma(ma, smoothingLength)
hist = ma - sigline + 50

//Histogram Color
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")

//Plotting
plot(hist, histbase=50, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=50 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(ma, title="EMA", color=color.green, offset=offset)
hline(50, "Median", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
plot(sigline, title="Smoothing Line", color=color.red, offset=offset, display=display.none)
lowband = plot(db, "LowBand", color.aqua)
highband = plot(ub, "HighBand", color.aqua)
fill(h1, h2, color=color.silver, transp=90)
fill(lowband, highband, color=color.gray, transp=90)
plot(crsi, "CRSI", color.fuchsia)
```

Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks for your time and effort. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a good explanation here: [Pine Script: IF vs IFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662632/pine-script-if-vs-iff)

```
"iff(crsi[m] >= testvalue, 1, 0)" should be "(crsi[m] >= testvalue ? 1 : 0)"
```